# How to make a Login layout similar to this reference?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating an application in which I want to make a login screen similar to this. Kindly suggest the design of the last part of **social media** login.

[image]

Comment: use constraint layout or relative layout.

Comment: Check https://www.uplabs.com/android , you will get a lots of idea for design related from marital up labs

Comment: yes I have tried but getting error in making the that kind of border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a xml file like this for social media login part
    =======

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="18dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/social_icons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Login With"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry the image was not uploading.

Comment: thanks for the exact design as required

Comment: Your Welcome :) @mahak